# How to get atomically incremented value in Firebase RTDB?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am using increment() to atomically generate a sequence number for orders:

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1)
```

Now, I would like to show that sequence number as orderID to the users. With transaction, I will have that sequence number on the client already:

```
var seq;
ref.transaction(function(value) {
  seq = (value || 0) + 1;
  return seq;
});
```

With increment(), how do I do that? Should I make another round trip to the server using once() or listen to changes using on()?

Comment: You could do either of those.

Comment: Do you mean, I have to do the roundtrip to the database to get the incremented value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the incremented value, you can indeed use either `once()` or `on()` to receive the updated the result.  You do, in fact, have to read it back from the server to know for certain the new value.

Comment: If there is a delay between the increment and read operation, then 2 competing threads will increment one after another, but they might read the same incremented data by +2, isn't it? Doesn't it beat the purpose of atomic increment?

Comment: You would have to perform the read only after the update succeeds.  You need to pay attention to the asynchronous result that says the values changed on the server.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If it is executed as increment1 > read1 > increment2 > read2, it should be fine. But, it can execute as increment1 > increment2 > read1 > read2, because of race condition, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I suggest posting as a new question and explain in more detail what your concern is.